# --prefer-dist installing Laravel 5.8 and not 6.x. with last version of composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am under composer version 1.9.1

I wonder why Laravel is installed with version 5.8.35 and not with version 6.x ?

[image]

I use this code (laravel6b is the name of my test project)

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel6b
```

Comment: What would happen if you require Laravel v6 explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because I have a PHP older[image]

Laravel 6 requires PHP 7.2